# For this Fsharp Charting Livechart example, why is the reference not set being thrown?

Tags: charts, f#

```
open System
open System.Windows

open FSharp.Charting
open FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes

[<STAThread>]
do
    let win = Window(Title="Chart")

    let data = [|for i=1 to 10 do yield (i, i*i)|]

    let e = Event<_>()
    let ev = e.Publish

    let chart = LiveChart.Line (ev) |> ChartControl
    let host = new Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost(Child=chart)
    win.Content <- host

    e.Trigger data // Throws an error here

    Application().Run(win) |> ignore
```

I am trying to figure out how F# Charting's Livecharts work, but most of the examples use timers or some other complicated stuff. The above is the simplest I could make it, but for some reason I keep getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception when I trigger the event.

Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: Here is the trace. I had to remove the catch in the above example to get the dump.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FSharp.Charting.NotifySeq.IObservable-1-ObserveOn@225-1.System-IObserver`1-OnNext(T value) in c:\GitHub\FSharp.Charting\src\FSharp.Charting.fs:line 226
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Event.h@174-1.Invoke(Object sender, T args)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpEvent`1.Trigger(T arg)
   at <StartupCode$Charts>.$Program.main@() in C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Poker Experiments\Charts\Program.fs:line 20
```

Comment: Care to provide the call stack?

Comment: Added the call stack. For some reason the debugger could not catch it.

Comment: Looking at the [FSCharting source code](https://github.com/fslaborg/FSharp.Charting/blob/master/src/FSharp.Charting.fs#L226), seems like there is no active synchronization context at time of subscribing. Try to do the subscribing in the window initialization, after the `Application.Run` call.

Comment: Wow, you were right. Thank you very much! Adding `win.Loaded.Add <| fun _ ->` in the line after `let win` makes it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [FSCharting source code](https://github.com/fslaborg/FSharp.Charting/blob/master/src/FSharp.Charting.fs#L226), seems like there is no active synchronization context at time of subscribing.

You should create the chart on window initialization, which would happen after the `Application.Run`, which creates the WPF synchronization context.